# How is velocity defined in circular motion in central force field?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, vectors, differentiation

In my view the velocity is change of displacement in the increasing direction of displacement.  Now in circular motion in central force field the particle is changing its direction then how is the velocity defined as the displacement is not even defined as it is not in a fixed direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, velocity is a vector.

The magnitude of this vector is a speed, which should not be difficult to define and calculate for a circular trajectory.

The direction of this vector is the tangent to the curvature of the trajectory, which is well defined for a circular trajectory although it is constantly changing.

If we can define the magnitude and the direction of a vector at any point, we can define the vector.

Comment: I read back in lower classes a rotating object does not have velocity but speed. As velocity is vector which has a particular direction.  But if I take velocity as a rotating vector then that resolves my doubt. Is it the right way to think?

Comment: @Nobodyrecognizeable We can think of a velocity of a point, which could move straight, rotate around a circle or follow a more complex trajectory. So, the velocity  vector of that point would not rotate (like a hand of a clock, i.e., in place), but rather change its direction following the curve of its trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

It still is defined that way.

$$ \mathbf{v} = \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt} = \frac{d(r \cdot \mathbf{\ \hat r})}{dt}. $$

But $r = R$ is constant for a circular path, so

$$ \mathbf{v} = R\frac{d\mathbf{\hat r}}{dt}. $$

Here $R\frac{d\mathbf{\hat r}}{dt}$ is the rate of the change radial unit vector, i.e., how fast the object is moving in the circular math. It is an angular speed, so

$$ v = R\omega.$$

More properly, with vectors (still starting from the first equation) you can derive $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{R}.$

Comment: I read back in lower classes a rotating object does not have velocity but speed. As velocity is vector which has a particular direction.  But if I take velocity as a rotating vector then that resolves my doubt. Is it the right way to think?

Comment: @Nobodyrecognizeable At each instant $t$ along the circular motion of the particle, the particle has a distinct velocity vector ${\vec v}(t)$. For pure circular motion, this vector always points tangent to the arc of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

> In my view the velocity is change of displacement in the **increasing direction of displacement**.

What does "increasing direction of displacement" mean?

Velocity is the rate of change of displacement with time.

Constant velocity is when the rate of change of displacement with time does not change - moving equal distances in equal intervals of time and always moving in the same direction.

Going round a corner the direction of travel changes, so the velocity must have changed, eg after going half way around a circular track the direction of motion is exactly opposite to the direction of motion at the start.

Comment: I read back in lower classes a rotating object does not have velocity but speed. As velocity is vector which has a particular direction.  But if I take velocity as a rotating vector then that resolves my doubt. Is it the right way to think?

Comment: @Nobodyrecognizeable You can have an object moving in a circle at constant speed but as its direction of motion id changing the velocity is not constant. So there is a rotation in the direction of the velocity vector